Why doesn't my dual boot (macOS/Linux Mint) iMac not boot after I deleted the Linux Mint partition?
I had a dual boot (macOS/Linux Mint) iMac (2017 27") for about a year, recently my iMac has not enough space so I wanted to remove Linux Mint.
In disk utility, I delete a 7GB swap partition and a 20GB partition for sharing files and merged with the partition where Linux Mint 21 was installed.
After that, macOS can not boot.
I ran macOS recovery mode, in terminal I saw the drive info like this:
Disk0: 
0:GUID_partition_scheme                  *1.0 TB    disk0 
1:EFI EFI                                 209.7 MB  disk0s1 
2:FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF    841.7 GB  disk0s2 
3:Linux filesystem                        120 GB    disk0s3

The second one, disk0s2 with strange name FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF should be the partition where macOS is installed.
For reference I found a post here in Super User which is a little similar problem, unfortunately my knowledge of running codes in terminal is very poor.
I tried also in macOS internet recovery mode to reinstall macOS, but there is no disk for me to choose to install.
I reinstalled Linux Mint on this 120 GB partition, which runs well, unfortunately it's impossible from there to access files in macOS partition which are my most concerns. Is there a way to access macOS files from Linux Mint or some other methods?
Is the disk0s2 partition repairable so the macOS will be able to boot?

This is the result from running lsblk:
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM    SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    0  931.5G  0 disk
├─sda1        8:1    0    200M  0 part
├─sda2        8:2    0  783.9G  0 part
└─sda3        8:3    0  147.5G  0 part /
nvme0n1     259:0    0   26.1G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0    300M  0 part /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   25.8G  0 part


I really hope someone can give me a little bit guidance. I would be happy to offer any other information to repair the problematic partition and make the macOS again bootable. Thank you!

You can use the lsblk command to determine the identifier used by Ubuntu to represent the drive. This command should be entered in an Ubuntu Terminal window.
You can enter the gdisk command to correct the partition table. Since Ubuntu is installed on a SATA HDD, you need to enter:
sudo gdisk /dev/sda

Otherwise, if the Ubuntu was installed on a PCIe SSD, then you probably need to enter:
sudo gdisk /dev/nvme0n1

The gdisk command is interactive. The input should come from the first column of the table given below.



Entry
Type
Comment




p
command
Print the partition table. The code for the second partition should be FFFF.


t
command
Change the partition's type code.


2
parameter
Partition number


af0a
parameter
Hex code


p
command
Print the partition table.


w
command
Write the table to disk and exit.


y
parameter
Confirm to proceed.




Note: The gdisk command does not write out any changes until the last entry is made. So, if you make a mistake, you can press the control+C key combination to exit and start over.

Basically, you need to change second partition's code from FFFF to AF0A, which is the code for Apple APFS. The codes are the way gdisk represents the actual UUIDs. The code AF0A represent the UUID value of 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC.
Installing and Uninstalling Linux on Macs as a Dual Boot.
Linux is usually installed by taking the following steps.

Use macOS to create space for a Linux install.
Use a Linux installer to create Linux partitions, then install Linux.

If uninstalling, the above steps should be repeated in reverse order, as given below.

Use a Linux installer to remove the Linux partitions.
Use macOS to return space to macOS.

If you try to use macOS to remove the Linux partitions, then you will be punished by Apple's software.  This software will disable the booting of macOS by changing the partition type to FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFF.

thank you! From the second part of your reply which is so clear and logical I finally understand how the dual boot system works.
About the First part of your reply. It was a macOS and Linux Mint dual boot. And I reinstalled Linux Mint 21 on the 120 GB partition yesterday, but it didn't help.
It was a macOS and Linux Mint dual boot.
I reinstalled Linux Mint on the 120 GB partition, but it didn't help.
This iMac has a 1TB Fusion Drive, consisting of a traditional SATA HDD and a small SSD for caching. Should I choose sudo gdisk /dev/sda to run lsblk command?

This is the result from running lsblk:
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS sda           8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  ├─sda1        8:1    0   200M  0 part  ├─sda2        8:2    0 783.9G  0 part  └─sda3        8:3    0 147.5G  0 part / nvme0n1     259:0    0  26.1G  0 disk  ├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   300M  0 part /boot/efi └─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0  25.8G  0 part 
I will try to upload a screenshort.
(https://imgur.com/a/jmWpxTs)

You would enter sudo gdisk /dev/sda.

This is the 2nd screenshot showing "sudo gdisk /dev/sda" then inside "p": (https://imgur.com/YrDMYFr)

What to enter into sudo gdisk /dev/sda is shown in the first column of the table given in my answer. The column is labeled "Entry".

I see. May I ask will this change delete my data?

No. The change is made to the GUID Partition Table (GPT). This table is not in the partition where your data is stored.

Great! So I should do:
sudo gdisk /dev/sda then
p then
t then
2 then
af0a then
p then
w then
y,
right?
Should I use capital letter to input "af0a"?
And that's all? What should I do aftar?
I am quite nervous because I am a newbie. Sorry for asking so many questions.
BTW, I saw other people solve this problem in the terminal in Mac Recovery mode, and much more complicated than in Linux. Is it so?

Make each entry followed by pressing the return key. The code af0a is hexadecimal and can be entered in upper or lower case. Afterwards, see if you can boot macOS.

Thanks for explanation and all the help, dear David. You are amazing! I will do it tomorrow when I feel fresher and will post the good news immediately.

This works like magic. I was struggling to solve this problem, and most suggestions from SuperUser involved using the macOS recovery mode terminal, which seemed a bit difficult. Your advice to handle it in Linux was perfect—it turned out to be a much simpler and more efficient solution. I’m really grateful for your generosity and for your impressive knowledge. Before executing gdisk in terminal I created a whole disk image in ext. ssd by Linux program Disks so that I was not afraid of any errors. Dear David, thank you so much for your help! your kindness is greatly appreciated.
